# How to get duration of speech synthesizer stream

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement, duration, speechsynthesizer

How can I measure duration of SpeechSynthesierStream before playing it please?

```
     SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
     SpeechSynthesisStream sss;
     ss.Voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices[3];
     sss = await ss.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello world.");
     MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
     mediaElement.SetSource(sss, sss.ContentType);

     //here I want to get the duration

     mediaElement.Play();
```

This code works just fine and speaks "Hello world.". After some time the mediaElement.NaturalDuration has also correct value. But I need to know duration of speech as soon as possible and before playing the speech. I added handler for mediaElement.MediaOpen, but this "SetSource" probably doesn't fire this event. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you attach the `MediaElement` to the visual tree? MediaOpen won't fire until it's attached to the visual tree and `NaturalDuration` should be available within the `MediaOpen` event.

Comment: After I attached mediaElement to visual tree the MediaOpened event started to work. Thank you for help.

Comment: You're welcome - I've added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `MediaOpen` to fire, you need to attach the `MediaElement` to the visual tree. Once you've attached the MediaElement to the visual tree, `NaturalDuration` should be available within the `MediaOpen` event.